# Prove that sgn is a homomorphism from $S_n\to\{1,-1\}$.

Tags: permutations, group-homomorphism

$\newcommand{\sgn}{\operatorname{sgn}}$Define $\sgn:S_{n}\to\left\{1,-1\right\}$ by

$\sgn(\sigma)=1$ if $\sigma$ is even, and $\sgn(\sigma)=-1$ if $\sigma$ is odd.

Prove that $\sgn$ is a homomorphism, where $\left\{1,-1\right\}$ is a group under multiplication.

Here is my attempt:

Proof. Let $\sgn$ be as defined and suppose $\alpha_1,\alpha_2$ are two odd permutations, while $\beta_1,\beta_2$ are two even permutations from $S_n$. It follows that $\alpha_1\alpha_2$ and $\beta_1\beta_2$ are even, while $\alpha_i\beta_i$ and $\beta_i\alpha_i$ are odd permutations for $i\in\left\{1,2\right\}$. Therefore under $\sgn$ we obtain:

\begin{align}
\sgn(\alpha_1\alpha_2) & =1=-1\cdot -1 = \sgn(\alpha_1)\sgn(\alpha_2) \\[10pt]
\sgn(\beta_1\beta_2) & =1=1\cdot 1 = \sgn(\beta_1)\sgn(\beta_2) \\[10pt]
\sgn(\alpha_i\beta_i) & =-1=-1\cdot 1 = \sgn(\alpha_i)\sgn(\beta_i) \\[10pt]
\sgn(\beta_i\alpha_i) & =-1=1\cdot -1 = \sgn(\beta_i)\sgn(\alpha_i)
\end{align}

Hence, for any $\sigma\in S_n$, $\sgn$ defines a homomorphism to $\left\{1,-1\right\}$. QED.

--

I am pretty sure this will suffice as a proof but I'd like feedback on anything that seems unusual or that could use some attention. In particular if there is a simpler way of doing this, please let me know.

Comment: Everything here depends entirely on your definition of "odd" and "even" permutation. This is a matter to which one must dedicate some attention, because the fact that, for all $\sigma$, "$\sigma$ can be decomposed into an odd number of transpositions" and "$\sigma$ can be decomposed into an even number of transpositions" are mutually exclusive is basically tantamount to proving that $\operatorname{sgn}$ is a well-defined homomorphism $S_n\to\{-1,1\}$.

Comment: Another possible approach: assume you've proven that $S_n$ has presentation $\langle \tau_1, \ldots, \tau_{n-1} \mid \tau_i^2 = 1, \tau_i \tau_j = \tau_j \tau_i \mathrm{~if~} |i-j|>1, \tau_i \tau_{i+1} \tau_i = \tau_{i+1} \tau_i \tau_{i+1} \rangle$ (with $\tau_i$ thought of as $(i ~ i+1)$).  Then it immediately follows there's a unique homomorphism $S_n \to \{ \pm 1 \}$ such that each $\tau_i$ is mapped to $-1$.

Comment: @G. Sassatelli so are you suggesting that must I show that sgn is well-defined also?

Comment: Here's the thing: you say that it $\text{odd}\circ \text{odd}=\text{even}$ is obvious. Since you appear to be resilient to stating definitions, let's pick one I want: "$\sigma$ is **odd** if and only if *there exist* a natural number $k$ and traspositions $\tau_1,,\cdots,\tau_{2k+1}$ such that $\sigma=\tau_1\circ\cdots\circ \tau_{2k+1}$" and "$\sigma$ is even if and only if it is not odd". Since transpositions generate the permutations, it's obvious that $\sigma$ is even if and only if *every* decomposition of $\sigma$ into transpositions consists of an even number of transpositions[continues]

Comment: Now, it is *obvious* that, if $\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_2$ are odd, *there exists at least one* decomposition of $\sigma_1\circ \sigma_2$ into an even number of transpositions... and so what? This is not the definition  of being even: there might be another decomposition into an odd number of transpositions. This basically happens for all definitions of parity of a permutation: you omit a piece of the result I have mentioned (which is tantamount to what you need to prove) and some "obvious" part of your work crumbles.

Comment: All good points and I will make note of them. Thanks for the insight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the proof is currently written, it could easily be interpreted as only proving (up to) six special cases of what you actually need to prove, which would not be sufficient.  It would be much clearer to start with: let $\alpha, \beta \in S_n$ be any two elements.  Then, you can split the proof into four cases according to whether $\alpha, \beta$ are even or odd in showing that $\sgn(\alpha\beta) = \sgn(\alpha) \sgn(\beta)$.  Your proof has the essential idea needed in each of the four cases, but only restricted to one or two special cases that you fixed beforehand.

As another way of stating my objection: at most, you have proved:

$$ \forall \alpha_1, \alpha_2, \beta_1, \beta_2 \in S_n, odd(\alpha_1) \wedge odd(\alpha_2) \wedge even(\beta_1) \wedge even(\beta_2) \rightarrow \\ \sgn(\alpha_1 \alpha_2) = \sgn(\alpha_1) \sgn(\alpha_2) \wedge \cdots \wedge \sgn(\beta_2 \alpha_2) = \sgn(\beta_2) \sgn(\alpha_2). $$
So from here, you would also need to make an argument as to why this would imply:
$$ \forall \alpha, \beta \in S_n, \sgn(\alpha \beta) = \sgn(\alpha) \sgn(\beta). $$
If you make this argument, you will find that it would make the overall proof be more convoluted than the proof outline I suggested.

Comment: Another possible issue: depending on your definition, you might consider $S_1$ to be valid (and isomorphic to the trivial group).  But in that case, there *are* no odd permutations $\alpha_1, \alpha_2$ to choose...

Comment: I see what you mean here and I thought about this possible issue. I agree with what you've stated and correct accordingly.